# Edit XML with python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a xml file where I had wanted to grab the string of `objlocation` and change the contents of the string.

This are the contents of the xml files I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<publish show="STATE">

    <pubgroup objtype="ELE" location="/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.xml">

        <member objidx="15283942" objlabel="anm" objlocation="/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.anm"/>

        <member objidx="15283952" objlabel="fbx" objlocation="/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001_M_WALK_None.fbx"/>

        <member objidx="15283962" objlabel="mov" objlocation="/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.mov"/>

        <member objidx="15283972" objlabel="libraryinfo" objlocation="/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.json"/>

        <member objidx="15283982" objlabel="thumbnail" objlocation="/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.mng"/>

    </pubgroup>
</publish>
```

I tried `.firstChild` or `.childNodes[]`, it is printing the out contents as my xml files. This is of the list of xml files that I am trying to parse where its format is about the same.

I am trying to do this is pythonic way

Comment: **How** are you parsing this file? Can you share your code please? If you are using the minidom, are you aware of the [warning at the top of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)? You'd be far better of using the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) instead.

Comment: I was actually using minidom that I grab off from an online tutorial. My bad on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily modify your `xml` file using the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
doc = parse('data.xml')
root = doc.getroot()
for t in root.iterfind('pubgroup/member'):
    t.attrib['objlocation'] = "spam"

doc.write('output.xml', xml_declaration=True)
```

The [`iterfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iterfind) method returns a `generator` function instead of `list` which is very convenient if your have `xml` file  is very large

Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<publish show="STATE">

    <pubgroup location="/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.xml" objtype="ELE">

        <member objidx="15283942" objlabel="anm" objlocation="spam" />

        <member objidx="15283952" objlabel="fbx" objlocation="spam" />

        <member objidx="15283962" objlabel="mov" objlocation="spam" />

        <member objidx="15283972" objlabel="libraryinfo" objlocation="spam" />

    <member objidx="15283982" objlabel="thumbnail" objlocation="spam" />

</pubgroup>
```

Here `spam` is `objlocation` new value.

Comment: just a question, say will it be possible if in the event, I had wanted to add/delete/edit the contents of a line? Eg. `<member objidx="15283942" objlabel="anm" objlocation="spam" />`?

Comment: @dissidia you can insert/remove  or edit any tag you want. You may need to read the documentation for more infos https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial

Answer (score 2):

The shortest code I can suggest:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
root = tree.parse('test.txt') # root represents <publish> tag

for member in root.findall('pubgroup/member'):
    print member.attrib['objlocation']
```

Output:

```
/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.anm
/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001_M_WALK_None.fbx
/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.mov
/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.json
/user_data/STATE/ITEM/character/ANM/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001/ANM_rig_WALK_sg_v001.mng
```

To make changes:

```
for member in root.findall('pubgroup/member'):
    member.attrib['objlocation'] = 'changed'
tree.write('output.txt')
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Was wondering if it is possible to edit just the `objlocation` of `objlabel="libraryinfo"`, while leaving the rest as it is?