# Is it possible to use Regular Expression to alter a string directly instead of returning altered version of the string?

Tags: python, regex, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to directly edit an XML file's text. I'd prefer to find and remove a certain phrase potentially by using the "sub" function. For particular reasons I'd prefer not to return the edited strings and then find a way to replace the existing XML file test. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Python strings are immutable...

Comment: So your saying I have no choice but to create a copy and swap the strings?

Comment: That's the easiest way. Another option is to use a [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) memory-mapped file object.

Comment: Note that in-file updates are only possible if the old and new strings have the exact same number of bytes.

Comment: I ended up going with the copy/swap method. Thanks a ton for your help, guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit XML with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274751/edit-xml-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

No, in Python you can not change strings in place as Python strings are immutable.